# How to use the word 'suitable' properly?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say, I'm exlaining a meaning of some words to someone giving specific situations as an example. And I want to say one of these sentences.
"This word is more suitable to this situation."
"This word is more suitable in this situation."
"This word is more suitable for this situation."
I'd like to know which one is correct.
And could you correct them if there is any mistakes I made in this thread? I'm not sure if I'm writing correctly.
Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt - as to whether the usage of a particular preposition is correct or not - just google "define [word]". In your case, it yields:

> **suitable**   /ˈsuːtəb(ə)l/ adjective
>
> right or appropriate for a particular person, purpose, or situation.
>   "these toys are not **suitable for** children under five"

Notice that your relevant part is highlighted in grey. It clearly indicates that "for" is the preposition you should be using here.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Additionally, if a word has more than one prepositional forms, they're all listed separately. Have a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOGCG.png).